# Get div's position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm not able to solve this problem on my own, so i decided to ask for help.

```
var x = $(change).offset().left;
var y = $(change).offset().top;
```

I have a page with an amount of divs with position:absolute. This two lines give me the position of a div inside my window-page. The problem is: how can i get the position of a outer page div?

For example: i click on a div that is displayed on the page, and javascript returns me the position of the below div, that is not displayed beacause of the overflow. The problem is that these lines returns only the displayed items, and returns null for everything not shown.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's
var x= $("div").position.top or .left or .right.. 
And the value comes in pixels (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

try this(no need jquery)

```
function getpos(x) {
   obj = document.getElementById(x);
   var left =obj.offsetLeft;
   var top = obj.offsetTop;
   return [left,top];
}
```

for example

```
getpos('logoen');
```